Xlib の XSetBackground() で思った通りに背景色を変更できない
Xlibを用いたプログラミングの途中で XSetBackground() が思った通りに動きません。
一度設定した前景と背景を後で変更する、という目的で XSetBackground() を使用しているのですが、私の環境では背景色が白から緑に更新されません。
理由がわかるようならご教示下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。
環境は以下の通りです。
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

問題のコードは以下です。
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    Display *display;
    int screen;
    Window window;
    XEvent ev;
    GC gc;
    Colormap colormap;
    XColor thiscolor, exactcolor;

    display = XOpenDisplay( NULL );
    screen = DefaultScreen( display );
    window = XCreateSimpleWindow( display,
        RootWindow( display, screen ),
        100, 50, 500, 400, 4,
        BlackPixel( display, screen ),
        WhitePixel( display, screen ));

    colormap = DefaultColormap( display, screen );
    XAllocNamedColor( display, colormap, "green", &thiscolor, &exactcolor );
 
    gc = XCreateGC( display, window, 0, 0 ); 
    XSetBackground( display, gc, thiscolor.pixel ); 
    
    XSelectInput( display, window, ExposureMask );

    XMapWindow( display, window );

    do{
        XNextEvent( display, &ev);
    }while( ev.type != Expose );

    XDrawLine( display, window, gc, 10, 100, 490, 300 );

    XFlush( display );

    getchar();
    XDestroyWindow( display, window);
    XCloseDisplay( display );

    return 0;
}


ウィンドウのバックグラウンドカラーを変更する場合は、XSetBackground ではなくXSetWindowBackground(display, window, thiscolor.pixel); を使います。

教えていただいた方法で解決しました！！
